# Interchange two values in matrix

Tags: image, matlab

I have a matrix containing only two types of values, 0 and 255. What is the most neat and efficient way of interchanging those values?

Comment: `255-input_matrix`?

Comment: Yes! I was able to calculate the matrix using the simple line

A = abs(255 - A);

Comment: or `~input_matrix*255`?

Comment: What does _ and ~ do?

Comment: `~` means _not_ and `_` is just part of the name (I changed my edit to use the same name convention as Divakar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the most efficient way, you should benchmark the different possibilities:

```
input_matrix = round(rand(2000))*255;

timeit(@() ~input_matrix*255) % 15.3 ms
timeit(@() 255-input_matrix) % 5.7ms
```

So, `255-input_matrix` is the best method. (Thanks to Divakar for this suggestion)